# Filtering data in a custom metric?

Tags: looker-studio

On a particular type of page, I have an event that fires every time someone enrolls in a product. The event is:

> ***Category***: Enroll
>   ***Action***: <    Name of Product    >
>   ***Label***: enroll

I am able to create a report that lists the number of times the event was fired on Pages by using the metric of `total events` and filtering by the label `enroll` This gives the page that it was fired on and the count of the event.

I'm now trying to do conversion rate. So, I'd want to get

```
(Total Events on the page (filtered by Event Label="enroll")) / Unique Pageviews
```

I can't figure out how to do the total events filtered in Data Studio using a calculated metric. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using REGEXP_MATCH in the sum of a case statement to achieve what you need.

Creating a metrics as follows and then do the division  by unique pageviews as a second metric.

```
 SUM(case when REGEXP_MATCH(Event Label, "enroll") then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: You're welcome. I think we're all still learning case when mixing dimensions / metrics. It doesn't always work as you'd expect!