# Google Data Studio: How to count number of specific events

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio, calculated-field

I know similar questions were asked before, but none of the answers that I found ([example here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/22779471?hl=en), [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822231/filtering-data-in-a-custom-metric)) helped me.

---

### What I am trying to do:

Create a report in Google Data Studio that shows me number of **Unique Page Views** VS **Specific Event**. For example: how many users visited page X, and how many of those clicked in button Y.

[image]
*(Example of what I am trying to achieve)* ☝️

---

### What I already have:

Google Analytics is configured and events are tracked. When I go to Google Analytics I can see the numbers there. Google Data Studio is already connected to my Google Analytics and the numbers are matching.

---

### What I tried so far:

**Test 1**

Create a chart using `Unique Page Views` and `Unique Events` metrics and set a filter with `Event Name = "Button clicked"`, but that filters my `Unique Page Views` metric and I end up with wrong numbers.

**Test 2**

Create a **Calculated Field** using:

```
SUM(case when REGEXP_MATCH(Event Action, "Button clicked") then 1 else 0 end)
```

or using:

```
COUNT(case when REGEXP_MATCH(Event Action, "Button clicked" ) then "Button clicked" else NULL end)
```

But this only returns `1`

---

Appreciate any other ideas

Comment: There is no _Unique Visitors_ metric in Google Analytic, _Visitors_ are already unique count. In test 1 you mentioned _Unique Page Views_, is it the metric that you want to put on the plot?

Comment: Sorry, that should by *Unique Page Views*, you are right. Fixed that in the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [data blending](https://youtu.be/UU5L6-k_L3g?t=88) feature:

1. Create first plot with *Visitors*/*Users* or *Unique Page View*.
2. Create second plot with *Unique Event* filtered as you want.
3. Select both plots, right-click on one of them, select *Blend data*.

Example (with addition of unfiltered plot for comparison):
[image: Plot comparison]

Comment: Sure, but this is kind of a workaround. Is there a way to keep only the blended plot / hide the first / second plot?

Comment: Hi @HugodeHeer - what do you mean by that? On the screenshot I included 4 plots just for the sake of comparison. After blending the data you can visualize any part of it you need. You don't have to keep plots used for creating a blend and you can create blend without making initial plots too by going into Resources > Manage blends and creating one.

Comment: Ah great! It creates a new blended dataset, so i can indeed remove the first en second plots Got it working now :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is related to Google Analytics 4 data, but that is how I wound up reading this post. I have found a solution. If you would like to pull specific events as a metric, just do the following:

```
SUM(IF(Event name - GA4="G1_COMPLETION",Event count - GA4,0))
```

Comment: I've tried exactly this on my report, and I get this error message:  
"
Sorry, calculated fields can't mix metrics (aggregated values) and dimensions (non-aggregated values). Please check the aggregation types of the fields used in this  formula. Learn more.  
"
("learn more" leads here: https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7569962#troubleshoot-calculated-fields&zippy=%2Cin-this-article)

Answer (score 0):

The post by Cmoz works for me, but after I first created a data extract, and ran the calculated field on that datasource

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution but in my case - I joined not just 2 tables but also it was necessary to join 1 more table just with the date.
Where we blend data - we join table 2 with table 1 and table 3 **with table 1 also**
[the result of blending data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7QwR.png)

[data blending setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRTMy.png)

[Join configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU8fl.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).